# Python and Matlab compute variances differently. Am I using the correct functions?

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, statistics

Consider the following array:

```
x=[80    55   304   115     5    24    72]
```

When I use `np.var(x)=8508.8164`, however, Matlab's `var(x) = 9.9270e+03`.  How can this be?  Is there a different function I should be using in Python?

Comment: I'm confident it stems from the default degrees of freedom being 0 for NumPy, as covered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600207/why-does-numpy-std-give-a-different-result-to-matlab-std) about `std()`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin - Correct.  I've marked that post as a duplicate.  Thanks for providing a link!

Comment: Thanks, Ill take a look at the other question.

Comment: @user3600497 - As a bonus, I've verified that providing `ddof=1` to `numpy.var` gives you the same result as `var()` in MATLAB. MATLAB: `x = [80 55 304 115 5 24 72]; format long g; var(x) --> 9926.95238095238`.  Python: `import numpy as np; x = np.array([80,55,304,115,5,24,72]); np.var(x, ddof=1) --> 9926.9523809523816`.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that too.  Thanks guys.