# Why is MATLAB calculation of standard deviation different than a hand calculation?

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

Matlab:

```
>> std( [3 2 2 3] )
ans =
    0.5774
```

Layman's interpretation of standard deviation per [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20calculate%20standard%20deviation):

```
Mean of {3,2,2,3} = 2.5
Deviation from mean for each value = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
Square of deviation from mean = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25}
Mean of the squares = 0.25
Square root of 0.25 = 0.5
Therefore Standard Deviation of {3,2,2,3} = 0.5
```

What did I muck up? I was foolishly expecting those two numbers to agree.

Comment: Caught by failure to read your Intro Stats  textbook :-) .  The reasons for using an unbiased estimator can be found there (or elsewhere on the webZ )

Comment: I was going through the basic stat package on khanacademy.com. I now vaguely recall this, but since it wasn't being mentioned in the problems there it didn't pop up. Hopefully it'll be covered later on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Matlab `std` computes the [*corrected* standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation). From `help std`:

> std normalizes Y by (N-1), where N is the sample size.  This is the
>       sqrt of an unbiased estimator of the variance of the population from
>       which X is drawn, as long as X consists of independent, identically
>       distributed samples.

So you have

```
Square of deviation from mean = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25}
```

Then you don't compute the actual root mean of the deviations, but `sqrt(sum([0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25])/3)`. Generally, `sum(square of deviation)/(N-1)` for a vector of length `N`.

**Update:** as [Leonid Beschastny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202461/leonid-beschastny) pointed out, you can get matlab to calculate the uncorrected standard deviation. Again, from `help std`:

> Y = std(X,1) normalizes by N and produces the square root of the second
>       moment of the sample about its mean.  std(X,0) is the same as std(X).

Comment: It's worth to mention that `std` can be used to calculate both corrected and uncorrected standard deviations, e.g. `std(A, 1)` will calculate uncorrected standard deviation of `A`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny thanks for the insight, I added it to my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600207/why-does-numpy-std-give-a-different-result-to-matlab-std