# Why does the standardization differ between Python's 'StandardScaler' and Matlab's 'zscore'?

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, data-processing

Why does the standardization with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` in Python differ to `zscore` in Matlab?

Example with `sklearn.preprocessing` in Python:

```py
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> scaler = StandardScaler()
>>> scaler.fit(data)
>>> print(scaler.mean_)
    [ 0.5  0.5]
>>> print(scaler.var_)
    [0.25 0.25]
>>> print(scaler.transform(data))
[[-1. -1.]
[-1. -1.]
[ 1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.]]
```

The same example in Matlab with `zscore` function:

```matlab
>> data = [[0, 0]; [0, 0]; [1, 1]; [1, 1]];
>> [Sd_data,mean,stdev] = zscore(data)

    Sd_data =
   -0.8660   -0.8660
   -0.8660   -0.8660
    0.8660    0.8660
    0.8660    0.8660

    mean =
    0.5000    0.5000

    stdev =
    0.5774    0.5774
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600207/why-does-numpy-std-give-a-different-result-to-matlab-std

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the issue lies with the degrees of freedom (ddof - the correction factor associated with the estimate of the standard deviation) which appears to be 0 by default with the `StandardScaler`.

As an alternative, `scipy.stats`'s `zscore` function allows you to control this parameter when scaling:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

zscore(data, ddof=1)
array([[-0.8660254, -0.8660254],
       [-0.8660254, -0.8660254],
       [ 0.8660254,  0.8660254],
       [ 0.8660254,  0.8660254]])
```

And you end up getting the same output as the matlab function. When you call `zscore` with `ddof=0`, you get the same output as the `StandardScaler`.