# going from numpy array to a pandas dataframe changes values

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

consider the following code:

```
dog = np.random.rand(10, 10)
frog = pd.DataFrame(dog, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
slog = StandardScaler()
mog = slog.fit_transform(frog.values)
frog[frog.columns] = mog
```

OK, now we should have a dataframe whose values should be the standard-scaled array. But:

```
frog.describe()
```

gives:

```
[![describe the dataframe][1]][1]
```

Note that the standard deviation is 1.05

While

```
np.std(mog, axis=0)
```

Gives the expected:

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

What gives?

Comment: I am not sure why the image is not showing up, but the standard deviation is 1.05 in all columns.

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600207/why-does-numpy-std-give-a-different-result-to-matlab-std

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) computed by the `describe` method uses the *sample* standard deviation, while `StandardScaler` uses the *population* standard deviation.  The only difference between the two is whether the sum of the squared differences from the mean is divided by `n-1` (for the sample st. dev.) or `n` (for the pop. std. dev.).

`numpy.std` computes the population st. dev. by default, but you can use it to compute the sample st. dev. by adding the argument `ddof=1`, and the result agrees with the values computed by `describe`:

```
In [54]: np.std(mog, axis=0, ddof=1)
Out[54]: 
array([1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255,
       1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255, 1.05409255])
```